# How can I solve this error on my Pentaho BI Server: “pentaho PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014”

Tags: mysql, localhost

I get this error when I set MySQL as repository:

```
PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014: Error while trying to execute startup sequence for org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.connection.datasource.dbcp.DynamicallyPooledDatasourceSystemListener
```

I work with Pentaho BI Server `pentaho-server-ce-7.1.0.0-12`. As mentioned in some forums, the error disappeared when I have commented the line:

```
<bean id="dynamicallyPooledDataSourceSystemListener" class="org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.connection.datasource.dbcp.DynamicallyPooledDatasourceSystemListener" />
```

However, I can't access with any account — even admin on the `localhost` — when I use that.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: See [advice1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36814480/pentahosystem-error-0014) and [advice2](https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/69245-PentahoSystem-ERROR_0014-Startup-Sequenz-org-pentaho-platform-scheduler-QuartzSys/).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I discovered that some Tomcat components were not owned by the user (`pentaho`) under which I am running the server.

First, I stopped the server.

Re-established ownership of my `pentaho` install folder and all subfolders.

```
sudo chown -R pentaho:pentaho *
```

I removed all contents under the following folder.

```
~/pentaho/pentaho/server/pentaho-server/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost
```

The Tomcat server will rebuild these folders and content when restarted.

Restarted the Pentaho server.

Answer (score 0):

This error can appear when jcr_user password was changed. Please follow pentaho installation documentation based on your server version to check it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).